# how to create pre install rule for cmake

Tags: cmake

I need to check, that user commited all changes to svn before installing project.
I tries to use:

```
INSTALL(CODE "exec_program(python ARGS \${TC_BUILD_ROOT}/bin/tc_check_uncommited.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} OUTPUT_VARIABLE POST_INST_OUT RETURN_VALUE POST_INST_RES)")
```

But it is not helps. Changing to **execute_process** does not helps
add_custom_target does not helps too:

```
add_custom_target(checkUncommited ALL COMMAND python ${TC_BUILD_ROOT}/bin/tc_check_uncommited.py ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

In this case this target always failed for uncommited source, even if i only build project (not installing).

*tc_check_uncommited.py is a simple script, that returns non-zero if sources is not commited.*